# Does format(..., justify = "left") on a dataframe also left-justify the column names?

Tags: r, format, dataframe, justify, output-formatting

I'm relatively new to R, so hopefully this is an easy fix.

Here's my problem:

```
x <- data.frame(c("Thing1", "Thing2", "Thing3", "Thing4", "Thing5"), c("Sizeable line of text", "more text", "I hope this aligns", "something", "help me"))
colnames(x) <- c("T", "Text")
format(x, justify = "left")

       T                  Text
1 Thing1 Sizeable line of text
2 Thing2 more text            
3 Thing3 I hope this aligns   
4 Thing4 not much             
5 Thing5 help me
```

How can I get the column names to align left with the rest of the dataframe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If it's for reporting purposes, you might want to look at something like the "pander" package.

Comment: It was just annoying me really. I'll check out pander, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# print object explicitly
print(x,right=F)
```

Comment: This works on an ordinary data.frame, but not on `dplyr:::print.tbl_df()`

Comment: What's `F` doing?

Comment: @not2qubit it is shortcut for FALSE. The right way should be right=FALSE.